# Interpreting integrals geometrically

Tags: calculus

In Apostol's Calculus, Volume $1$, section $2.19$ in the exercises, in exercise $17$ the question was to find all real values of $x$, such that
$$\int_{0}^{x} \left(t^{3} - t \right)dt = \dfrac{1}{3} \int_{\sqrt{2}}^{x} \left( t- t^{3} \right) \; dt$$

I have solved it, arrived to the last step where,
$$\dfrac{x^{4}}{4}-\dfrac{x^{2}}{2}=-\dfrac{1}{3}\left(  \dfrac{x^{4}}{4}-\dfrac{x^{2}}{2}\right)$$
and found that 
$$x=0 \quad \text{and} \quad x=\pm \sqrt{2}$$

what I don't understand is the question later on asked to draw a suitable figure and interpet the equation geometrically, do I sketch both of the functions on the integral and shade the area of integration after I plot the $x$ values as limits? And if so, what would the limits of integration be? From $-\sqrt{2}$ to $0$ and from $0$ to $\sqrt{2}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There aren't really two functions, are there, once you take the minus sign out?

I'd sketch the graph of the integrand you see on the LHS:

[image: f(x) = x^3 - x]

and say
$x = 0$ means the LHS vanishes trivially, while the RHS vanishes since the area below the graph from $x = 0$ to $x = 1$ equals the area above the graph from $x = 1$ to $x = \sqrt{2}$.

I'll leave you to write down similar statements for the other 2 cases.

Comment: I was going to graph it as in the link https://www.desmos.com/calculator/k6aelamkhb, I am a bit confused because I don't understand what the question is really asking for.

Comment: Does that make sense now, though? Or is there anything you need me to clarify?

Comment: Yes it does, thank you :)

Comment: You're welcome, thanks for the upvote